# How to speed up an iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, performance

My iPad 2 (32gb) is about one year old and he is getting very slow. I've tried restarting the iPad and quitting all apps but with no real success.
There is about 5 GB of free storage space.

Any other ideas on how to speed things up?

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? Do you notice a big difference between now and a few weeks earlier?

Comment: I'll give one example of "slow"/"sluggish": when I open safari it sometimes takes ~10sec to "load". I.e., until you see the open pages and the search bar is active. 
To answer your second question: yes, I think this sluggishness started in the last few weeks.

Comment: What did you do the last few weeks? Installed something? Perform a jailbreak? Is it only Safari? Or other apps too?

Comment: no jailbreak. I installed a few apps here and there. I think it's mostly safari but also other apps (you can really see it on the Twitter and Facebook apps).

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried backing it up to your computer, then restoring it? That might help. Make sure it's backed up.